# Why is my dropdown not working correctly?

Tags: html, css

I am building a personal website, and want to get a dropdown menu working.  So far the first part is working, but the second (dropdown in dropdown) isn't.

It is the "Alternate History" line that isn't showing up.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

#links img,
footer img,
li img,
h1 img,
h2 img,
h3 img,
p img,
.dropme img {
  height: 1em;
}

footer {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 2em;
}

body {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #111;
  color: #eee;
}

html {
  padding-bottom: 500px;
}

dt {
  color: orange;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

dd {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: -1px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.68);
}

h1 {
  color: red;
}

h2 {
  color: goldenrod;
}

h3 {
  color: teal;
}

a {
  color: lime;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.menubar li a {
  display: block;
}

.menubar {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  zoom: 1;
}

nav {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
}

.menubar li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 1.5em;
  background: #222;
  border: #444 solid 2px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 4px;
}

.menubar li:hover {
  background: #000;
}

.menubar a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menubar li ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.menubar li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: -7px;
}

.menubar li ul li {
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: left;
}

code {
  color: green;
  /* overflow-x: auto; */
}


/* pre { */


/*     background: var(--color256); */


/*     border: 1px solid var(--color8); */


/*     border-radius: 4px; */


/*     padding: 5px; */


/*     display: block; */


/*     align: center; */


/*     max-width: 900px; */


/*     /1* background: #1d2021; *1/ */


/* } */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Smash Civilization's Homepage</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul class="menubar">

      <h1><big>Smash Civilization</big></h1>
      <div id="links">
        <div class="cat">
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="Literature.html">Literature</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="Literature.html">Category</a></li>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="AlternateHistory.html">Alternate History</a></li>

              </ul>
              <li><a href="Dewey.html">Dewey Decimal</a></li>
            </ul>
            <li><a href="Issues.html">Issues</a></li>
            <li><a href="Podcasts.html">Podcasts</a></li>
            <li><a href="Talks.html">Talks</a></li>
            <li><a href="Vision.html">Vision</a></li>

        </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

What do I need to fix to get this working correctly?  Any help is most appreciated!

Comment: Hi can you specify the code to what you are looking for. The code looks incomplete

Comment: I apologize if I didnt make it clear before, im still new to adding (What i consider) more complex html/css).  Im looking to make "<li><a href="AlternateHistory.html">Alternate History</a></li>" work correctly (dropdown in a dropdown).

Comment: For starters you have a few minor HTML structure issues. 1. you were missing a closing `div` and closing `nav`, and a `body` tag. I added these and edited your question to include a snippet so we can preview it right on SO. 2. `li` is basically the only valid child elements of `ul` (see Permitted content at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul), so `h1` and `div` shouldn't be nested under `<ul class="menubar">`. I would first make sure your HTML is valid before moving on to adjust the CSS. Invalid HTML may be visualized inconsistently across different browsers.

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options is an example validator you can use. Just paste in your HTML and it will tell you what might need correcting.

Comment: @CharlesRayburn https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h you can see an example on dropdown within a dropdown. This will help you implement